# CSS combine table styles

Tags: css

I've found similar tops for combining classes using the comma to separate them; however when I try it with the table class only the last table is receiving the style. Here is a small sample of what I'm trying to clean up:

```
table.tslist { 
    font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    cellspacing: 0; 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
    width: 225;    
}
table.djrlist { 
    font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    cellspacing: 0; 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
    width: 225;    
}
table.vacation { 
    font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    cellspacing: 0; 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
    width: 225;    
}
table.tslist td { 
    border-left: 1px solid #999; 
    border-top: 1px solid #999;  
    padding: 2px 4px;
}
table.djrlist td { 
    border-left: 1px solid #999; 
    border-top: 1px solid #999;  
    padding: 2px 4px;
}
table.vacation td { 
    border-left: 1px solid #999; 
    border-top: 1px solid #999;  
    padding: 2px 4px;
}
```

As I mentioned I tried `table.tslist, table.djrlist, table.vacation {....}` but no luck.

Comment: can you post the HTML?

Comment: Can you post excactly what your combined looks like? Because what your telling is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are doing something like this:

```
table.x, table.y td { }
```

and assuming that it'll expand out and apply to all the TD elements. It won't. You need something like this instead:

```
table.x td, table.y td { }
```

Comment: Thank you - your response is exatly what I was assuming to take place.  correcting such fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to include the element type in your seperators:

```
table.tslist,
table.djrlist,
table.vacation
{ 
    font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    cellspacing: 0; 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
    width: 225;    
}
table.tslist td, <-----
table.djrlist td, <-----
table.vacation td <----- { 
    border-left: 1px solid #999; 
    border-top: 1px solid #999;  
    padding: 2px 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you don't even need to do multiple styles like that. Classes are not like IDs, you can use them more than once.

If all of your tables are styled the same, just replace all of this:

```
 <table class="tslist">...</table>
 <table class="vacation">...</table>
 <table class="djrlist">...</table>
```

with

```
 <table class="tslist">...</table>
 <table class="tslist">...</table>
 <table class="tslist">...</table>
```

You can then remove the unused style entries from the css file.

Comment: You are correct; however, I start to have variation in additional styles.  thinking about it I suppose i could just apply multiple classes to accomplish the same.  However I was taking from other code I create within my site.  And I wanted to do a little house keeping to clean up the redundant code.